# Heap Corruption Detected when trying to delete an object (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, object, string-literals

I'm having problems with deleting an object at the end of my program. This is for a C++ course so we aren't allowed to use the string class (yet). I have a Weapon class that generates a name for a weapon, this name is instantiated with `char* result = new char[len]` which is then returned to the constructor. In the destructor I remove the name object with `delete[] this->name`.

Problem:

When I run my program, everything runs fine until the program comes to the deletion part of the program. Then I get this error message:

> Debug Error!
>
> Program: ... path to program ...
>
> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#198) at 0x0100B918. CRT
>   detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap
>   buffer.
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)

I have tried replacing delete with delete[] and vice versa, and it makes no difference.

Can anyone spot where I want wrong?

main.cpp:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

    // ... code ...

    Weapon* weapon = new Weapon();

    // ... code ...

    delete weapon;

}
```

Weapon.cpp:

```
Weapon::Weapon() {
    this->name = this->generateName();
    // more properties...
}

Weapon::~Weapon() {
    delete[] this->name;
    this->name = nullptr;
}

char* Weapon::generateName() {
    int pr, tp, su; // random variables for picking prefix, type and suffix

    const char *prefix[10] = { // ... a bunch of names ... };
    const char *type[10] = { // ... a bunch of names ... };
    const char *suffix[10] = { // ... a bunch of names ... };

    pr = rand() % 9;
    tp = rand() % 9;
    su = rand() % 9;

    int len = strlen(prefix[pr]) + strlen(type[tp]) + strlen(suffix[su]) + 1;
    char *result = new char[len]();
    strcpy(result, prefix[pr]);
    strcat(result, " ");
    strcat(result, type[tp]);
    strcat(result, " ");
    strcat(result, suffix[su]);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You're most likely overflowing `result` - writing more than was allocated.

Comment: "This is for a C++ course so we aren't allowed to use the string class (yet)." Sigh. The awesomeness of CS continues. Dont learn the most useful language features and dont ever,ever mention the use of debuggers and debugging techniques

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to allocate room in the string for the spaces :

```
int len = strlen(prefix[pr]) + strlen(type[tp]) + strlen(suffix[su]) + 1;
```

should be :

```
int len = strlen(prefix[pr]) + 1 + strlen(type[tp]) + 1 + strlen(suffix[su]) + 1;
```

The two extra characters would have overwritten memory beyond the allocated block, which accounts for the detected heap corruption.

Comment: Wow... Thanks a lot for spotting that :)

Comment: Alternatively, use std::string so you don't have to worry about these mistakes.
Though since std::string doesn't have a "release" function, you would have to change generateName's signature

Comment: Yes, I would love to use string class. Hopefully next assignment will allow us to use that.